# Sorting, how should I cout the round and pass?

Tags: c++, sorting

Our professor told us to make our program cout the round and pass of the sorting algorithm.. What should I do then?

[image]

https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-21f7faf7e69c3317661f5f959008e031?convert_to_webp=true

Like this one ^

**Bubble sort code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  return 0;
}
```

Is this right??? --->

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[100],c[100],b,n,i,temp;
  printf("\t\t\tBUBBLE SORT\n");
  printf("Enter total numbers : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter %d number : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    c[i]=a[i];
  }
  printf("\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
      b=0;
      if(a[j]<a[j+1])
      {   b++;
        temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j+1];
        a[j+1]=temp;
      }
      if(b!=0)
      {
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
          printf("%d  ",a[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\nAssending order By Bubble sort\n\t");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%d  ",c[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the yellow table is an example of the output you want?

Comment: not exactly, 

just like this one


{ 9, 5, 3, 4, 2 } ||


5, 3, 4, 2, 9 ||
3, 4, 2, 5, 9 ||
3, 2, 4, 5, 9 ||
2, 3, 4, 5, 9 ||

Comment: Can you step through the code by eye? Can you see when you should print out the contents of `array`?

Comment: uhmmm after the sorted list???

Comment: wait uhmm, can you give me a hint.. what array should i cout? array[c], array[d] or array[d+1]?

Comment: https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-21f7faf7e69c3317661f5f959008e031?convert_to_webp=true

|| see this example

Comment: There's only one array, and it's called `array`. The initial state of the array is `{9, 5, 3, 4, 2}`. Can you work through the code by eye and see when it becomes `{5, 3, 4, 2, 9}`?

Comment: Do you know how a `for` loop works? Can you identify the part of the code that prints the array at the end of the sorting? (I don't mind explaining the basics, I just want to know where to start.)

Comment: yes. this one

for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);

Comment: can you check if the new codes are correct? i dont have c++ here in this pc.. im only using cpp.sh

Comment: It's correct, as far as "6 5 4 2 1". So you have the first half done.

Comment: thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just simple step by step bubble sort problem.
just make two functions as bubble_asc(), bubble_desc()
and call it from the main function().

```
int main() {
...
bubble_asc();
bubble_desc();
...
}

void bubble_asc() {
...
do step by step bubble sort with ascending order here.
for(~~~~~) {
    for(~~~~~~) {
        if(array[a] < array[b])
             ....
        }
 }
 print arrays here..
}
void bubble_desc() {
...
do step by step bubble sort with descending order here.
for(~~~~~) {
    for(~~~~~~) {
        if(array[a] > array[b])
             ....
        }
 }
 print arrays here..
}
```